# Текущий id добавляемой записи

Tags: mysql

Как получить id записи (id AUTO_INCREMENT) записи, которую я сейчас хочу добавить?

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM name_table
```

А потом +1 не подходит, т.к. приведу пример:

Пусть есть таблица с id: 1,2,3. Удаляем последний id. Добавляем запись и запись добавится с id = 4, а запрос вернет мне 2.

Нет ли какой переменной в mysql типа NEXT_AUTO_INCREMENT или CURRENT ?

Собственно, зачем мне это нужно? Есть таблица users - логины и пароли юзеров. И есть вход через социалки. При входе через соц. сеть нужно записать его в эту таблицу, чтобы в остальном коде ему назначилась роль (права). Таблица ролей связана с этой таблицей users. Нужно записать нечто уникальное в поля username и email. Я записываю social_[id записи], дабы быть уверенным, что запись никальна.

Можно составить username из [имя соц. сети]_[id юзера на этой соц сети] - оно тоже будет уникальным. Но первый вариант мне казался проще.

Теперь помогите принять решение (1 или 2):

1. Записывать "пустую" (незначащую) запись (тоже надо еще придумать как, чтобы она была уникальной), считать ее id и обновить ее с учетом этого id - он-то уже никуда не денется.
2. Составить имя из [имя соц. сети]_[id юзера на этой соц сети] - оно тоже будет уникальным.

Хотел прибегнуть к 1-му варианту, т.к. казался проще.

Еще более общее описание зачем это надо.
  Пишу на (или под) фреймворке yii. Есть связка расширений yii-user + rights. Прикручиваю расширение eauth - вход через социалки. Нужно заставить расширение eauth использовать класс авторизации из yii-user, а не свой собственный. Для этого нужно занести аккаунт в таблицу users, откуда yii-user "возьмет" аккаунт и авторизует, не подозревая о "подмене". Там свяжется с rights и все будет ОК. Такое решение мне показалось наиболее простым. Если кто-то делал подобную связку, прошу подсказать как вы это делали. Пожалуй вынесу это в отдельный вопрос.

Comment: получи его после вставки

Comment: @nMike, он нужен мне до вставки)

Comment: Тут есть небольшая проблема... Собственно, если вы хотите быть на 100% уверенным в том, что эта запись, в случае добавления, будет иметь именно тот id, который вы получите, то нужно лочить таблицу на запись, т.к. может произойти следующее:

    php1: вы вытянули id
    php2: вставил запись сразу-же после этого
    php1: пытаетесь вставить - вряд-ли ошибка вида mysql error duplicate entry ... for key ..., чего вы ожидаете

Comment: А нужно ли что-то писать в username? Возможно, NULL сойдет? Нет юзернейма же, как раз.

Comment: @drdaeman, да там поле UNIQUE.
П.С. Обновил пост, может наведет кто на другое решение проблемы.

Comment: Кхм. Еесли я все правильно помню, UNIQUE-констрейнт не мешает NULL'ам, т.к. NULL != NULL. Он мешает только неуникальным не-NULL'овым значениям.

Как работает yii не знаю, ни разу в глаза не видел.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дополнение: Другой вариант, раз хочется просто иметь уникальные «имена» пользователей: засунуть туда GUID'ы и не ломать голову.

По крайней мере, что «`social_1234`», что «`social_b51c874f-a1a4-4416-badb-c1cfa7d81562`» — практически одинаково бессмысленны, непригодны к показу на сайте и годятся только для внутренних идентификаторов-заглушек. А как красиво выглядит такой идентификатор значения не имеет.

Или, я бы использовал `username = NULL`, если фреймворку не снесет это голову. Семантически, вроде бы, самое оно — аккаунт, на данный момент, *не имеющий* имени пользователя. UNIQUE-констрейнту, насколько я в курсе, NULL'ы не помеха.

---

Если очень надо — можно не использовать `AUTO_INCREMENT`, а руками сделать аналог `SEQUENCE`'ов из PostgreSQL.

Заведем таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE sequences (
    id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    value INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

И сделаем подобие `nextval()`. Удобного `RETURNING` у нас тоже нет, так что поступим как-то в духе:

```
SELECT value FROM sequences WHERE id = '...' FOR UPDATE;
...
UPDATE sequences SET value = ... WHERE id = '...';
```

Или, как вариант:

```
UPDATE sequences WHERE id = '...' SET value = @value := value + 1;
SELECT @value;
```

Первый вариант возвращал *имеющееся* значение, и потом увеличивал его, а второй — *инкрементированное*, как это происходит в PostgreSQL. Разницы для нас никакой (разве что `DEFAULT` выберем 0 или 1), главное не смешивать подходы.

Для удобства, пожалуй, завернем все в функцию в духе:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `nextval` (`seq_id` VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS INTEGER NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE current_value INTEGER;
    SELECT value INTO current_value FROM sequences WHERE id = seq_id FOR UPDATE;
    IF current_value IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE sequences SET value = current_value + 1 WHERE id = seq_id;
    END IF;
    RETURN current_value;
END;
```

Или как-то так оно там, я с MySQL знаком мало.

И все сведется к:

```
SELECT nextval('foo_id_seq') AS new_id;
```

Увы, сделать `CREATE TABLE ... (id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('..._id_seq') PRIMARY KEY, ...)` нам, вроде бы, не дадут (хотя можно попробовать), ну, оно не сильно и нужно.

Не забываем при этом, что уровень изоляции *не* должен быть `READ UNCOMMITTED`, иначе все сломается. И engine, в худшем случае, хотя бы таблицы `sequences`, должен поддерживать транзакции, т.е., это, в частности, *не* должен быть ISAM. Ну, как сломается, если констрейнты есть, то вставить ряд-дубликат нам, конечно, не дадут, но случайные отказы — некрасиво.

Вот таким образом мы построили генератор уникальных значений. Теперь выкидываем `AUTO_INCREMENT` из `name_table` и используем наши самодельные идентификаторы.

Comment: Дело в том, что этот вариант, все равно, не решает вопрос с блокировками. Человеку очень сильно нужно знать, какой у него будет значение автоинкремента еще до вставки. А это, без блокировок, не решается. Точнее, решается, но только в частном случае, когда к базе подключен один пользователь.

А уровень изоляции в MySQL распространяется не на всетипы таблиц.

Comment: @KiTE: Э-э-э, а что, в MySQL запрос `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, при живом-то индексе (PK), не заблокирует ряд от параллельных транзакций?

Ну а на ISAM — ССЗБ. Нужно InnoDB или что-то в этом дуже, по крайней мере на `sequences`. Или самому городить блокировки, да.

Comment: @KiTE, ерунду говорите, при помощи транзакций в InnoDB прекрасно решается. Только нужно добавить в хранимку `BEGIN;` и `COMMIT;` соответственно:

    BEGIN;
    SELECT value INTO current_value ...

    -- ...

    COMMIT;
    RETURN current_value;

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, где именно в моих словах ерунда?

    SELECT value INTO current_value ... FOR UPDATE;

Это ли не один из вариантов блокировок, как впрочем и транзакции?

Comment: @KiTE, в первом предложении:

> Дело в том, что этот вариант, все равно, не решает вопрос с блокировками.

Именно-таки решает, причем весьма неплохо.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, этой фразой я подразумевал, что для того чтобы получить значение автоинкремента до добавления новой записи, и во время обработки  это значение не успело бы устареть - нужны блокировки. Также я писал что "уровень изоляции в MySQL распространяется не на все типы таблиц". В случае с InnoDB - все тип-топ, а в случае с MyISAM блокировка `SELECT FOR UPDATE` не сработает, потому что она работает только в транзакциях. И, еще, BEGIN/COMMIT в хранимке не нужен. Процедуры и функции выполняются как атомарные операции (внутренняя транзакция создается автоматически).

Comment: Признаю, с BEGIN COMMIT был не прав. 

В остальном предлагаю закончить демагогию, данный способ вполне решает проблему ТС.

Comment: @drdaeman, отличная идея. Но я решил что буду использовать [имя_сервиса]_[id на этом сервисе]. А Вам спасибо огромное за помощь)

Answer (score 4):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM  `БД` LIKE  'Таблица'
```

В выдаче будет поле Auto_increment, извлекать его стандартными методами.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно работает)

Comment: ненадежно, если не лочить таблицу.

Comment: хотели получить AUTO_INCREMENT - вот ответ

Answer (score 3):

Прочитать текущее значение автоинкремента и прибавить к нему 1 - не проблема. Но где гарантии, что в промежутке между тем, как ты это сделаешь, обработаешь значение и попытаешься записать, не проскочит еще одна и более вставок в эту таблицу, которые сделают полученную информацию с автоинкрементом устаревшей?

Тут, мне кажется, нужно либо пересмотреть логику в сторону получения `id` через `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (эта функция работает в рамках одного подключения), либо использовать блокировки, чтобы приостановить запись в таблицу на время обработки полученного значения автоинкремента.

Comment: @KiTE, верное замечание. Но как воспользоваться LAST_INSERT_ID(), если он работает только после insert ? придется сделать запись, а потом считать? далее удалить вставленную запись? Или есть иные пути?

Comment: Опиши подробнее что должно из этого всего получиться. Возможно есть решения "в обход".

Ну, или - юзай блокировки.

Comment: А зачем требуется знать ID до того, как оно будет существовать?

Comment: @drdaeman, обновил главный пост.

Answer (score 0):

А как насчет [`LAST_INSERT_ID`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)?

Comment: Он хочет *до* вставки, а не после.

Само желание, собственно говоря, пагубно — потому что *до* вставки значение не определено.

А после вставки — конечно, оно самое.

Comment: Ну тогда наверное **MAX (id)** будет возвращать последний **ID** , но какая от него польза? если действительно кто то может делать вставку параллельно.

**Как один из возможных вариантов**
 делаем **INSERT** пустой полностью , получаем **Last_INSERT_ID** , запоминаем его в программе и уже полные данные вставляем не **INSERT** а при помощи **UPDATE where id** = наш запомненый **ID**

Comment: @savro, а как насчет сделать "пустой insert", считать его id и сделать update этой записи? id этот уже никак не изменится...

Comment: Ну так конкретезируйте чего вы хотите добиться. 
Опишите задачу более конкретно, зачем вам получать перед вставкой ID

Comment: @savro, обновил главный пост.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Получаешь последний ID записи из таблицы.
Вариант подходит даже для таблиц, где нет AUTO_INCREMENT.